# How can i set product attribute base in premalink

Tags: wordpress, url, woocommerce, permalinks

I m using wordpress and create a book selling store, I just want to filter my books on the basis of publishers, Publisher is the custom attribute in woocommerce.

What should be my product attribute base if i want to filter books based on publishers, if i add "shop" in "product attribute base" it show 404 page not found error.

Code is:

```
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );
            query_posts( $args );
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            global $product;
                $attr = get_post_meta($product->id, '_product_attributes', true);   
            $attr_label = $attr['publisher'];
            $m = $attr_label["value"]; /*Just for removing the array Vs string php 5+ warning*/
            $d[$m] = "1"; /* making  a unique array*/
        endwhile;
            wp_reset_query();
            ksort($d);
            /* Throwing an out put now */
             echo "<ul>";
              foreach($d as $index=>$val){
                  echo "<li><a href=''>".$index."</a></li>";
             }
```

Comment: Some code would help...

Comment: @ dingo_d , Description: In a website a seperate page in which all the publisher names listed already did by fetching the all values from databse, query of fetching data is done, now just need to put the url on the names of publishes like this <a href = " ? ">Publisher name</a>, I just want to set "herf="

Comment: How did you query your data? Using `WP_Query`? Show some kind of code so that people know what to work with. Did you try with `get_permalink()`?

Comment: @dingo_d, See the latest edit

Answer (score 1):

First you should never use query_posts() for querying posts in theme. Use `WP_Query()` instead.

Something like this

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => -1 );

$post = new WP_Query($args);
$out = '';

if ($post->have_posts()){
    while ($post->have_posts()){
        $post->the_post();
        global $product;
        $attr = get_post_meta($product->id, '_product_attributes', true);
        $attr_label = $attr['publisher'];
        $m = $attr_label["value"]; /*Just for removing the array Vs string php 5+ warning*/
        $d[$m] = "1"; /* making  a unique array*/

        ksort($d);
        foreach($d as $index=>$val){
            $out.= '<li><a href="">'.$index.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();

return '<ul>'.$out.'</ul>';
```

Now I don't know what else you have stored in the `_product_attributes` (you can always `print_r()` it out to see), but if you have stored the url value that you need you could access it in the same way like label with

```
$publisher_url = $attr_label['url'];
```

And then just put this in your href value

```
$out.= '<li><a href="'.esc_url($publisher_url).'">'.$index.'</a></li>';
```

Hope this guides you in the right direction.

Comment: Well I just put a 'dummy' variable inside. What other labels do you have inside besides 'value'? Do a `print_r($attr)` and you'll see an array with `publisher` key and values inside. If you have some values that give the url of the publisher, use this value in the `$publisher_url` variable.

Comment: Tried, It shows   `Array 
(
    [publisher] => Array
        (
            [name] => publisher
            [value] => CSJS
            [is_taxonomy] => 0
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
        )

    [isbn] => Array
        (
            [name] => isbn
            [value] => 81-7601-911-9
            [is_taxonomy] => 0
            [position] => 0
            [is_visible] => 1
            [is_variation] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: Well then your issue is that you don't have the url attribute. Try adding it in the attribute list besides `isbn` and `publisher`. And to every publisher you can then assign the url of the publisher, and extract it like you've extracted the value of the publisher. First put `$attr_url = $attr['url']; $attr_url_href = $attr_url['value'];` and put it in the array and pull it out in the `foreach`.

Comment: thanks Buddy, But i m new in it, suggest me how can i add a custom attribute url and then filter products after click on it... Many thanks

Comment: Ok, so you've added `isbn` and `publisher` in Products > Attributes menu. There you can add attribute called url, and fill in your publisher url's. Then by using the above method in the comment, you'll get set of url's. You just need to append it to the array `$d` and extract it in foreach. you can create the array like `$d[$m] = $attr_url_href`, and then in the foreach the `$val` should be the href value for each publisher.

Comment: OKay, Right Now  "publisher" attribute added from wordpress dashboard and listed information is **slug:publisher, type:text**, Now i m again back to the file where i put the recommended code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83729/discussion-between-rahul-bajaj-and-dingo-d).